# Is it safe to remove VS Code's ~/.config/Code/Cache and ~/.config/Code/CachedData directories?

Tags: visual-studio-code

`~/.config/Code` folder has 2 big folders:

```
313mb   ./Cache
193mb   ./CachedData
```

How can these be safely cleared once in a while? (eg. before making a backup)

Will simply deleting them cause any issue?

Answer (score 6):

VSCode clears the cache every 8 days or 3 months depending on the version.  I've manually cleared mine before backups without any issues.

[Cache, CachedData taking up quite some disk space #29960](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29960)

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe to remove them. VS Code itself will clear up old entries in these caches periodically.

Quoting from Johannes Rieken in [Cache, CachedData taking up quite some disk space #29960](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29960):

> Yes, we do clean it up and delete every thing older than 3 months: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/electron-browser/nodeCachedDataManager.ts#L69.
>
> For insider we now delete everything older 8 days, for stable older 3 months