# How to clean up VS code junk?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Over time, it looks like my VS Code has accumulated lot of junk:

```
> du -sh ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/
1.5G    /Users/m2/Library/Application Support/Code/
```

Is there any tutorial that shows how to cleanup all the junk accumulated by VS Code (on Mac)? What is safe to delete and what is not?

Comment: These are probably old versions of the app that you've upgraded over time

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61056128/11107541. given that https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132509 is closed by the vscode maintainers as a dup of the more targetted https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32461, which is covered in my answer post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75666552/11107541), I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61056128/11107541, but I'll hold off on that.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/47974678/11107541